# Dilemma with Watermark on KeyDown

Tags: c#, silverlight, keydown

I have a problem with watermark keydown. I have a keydown event handler like this.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();

            if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == txtPassword)
                btnLogin.Focus();
            else if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == txtUserName)
                txtPassword.Focus();
            else
                txtUserName.Focus();
        }
```

it works fine, but when the focus is on btnLogin, when you press tab, the focus goes straight to password box. I have inserted breakpoints to no avail. It only passes on the code once, and it enters the else statement. Any ideas? Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are not using the builtin tabbing functionality?

Comment: @competent_tech yes. It is because we are having some technical issues running this app on MAC. The problem on Mac is that when I tab from txtUserName, the tabbing goes to the address bar on the browser. That's why I am trying to hard-code this one.

Comment: Ouch. I'm assuming you checked the tabindexes on the controls to be sure they are in the correct order in case the mac implementation is just picking those up?

Comment: Also, make sure the TabNavigation is not set to Once.

Comment: @competent_tech yes, that was the first thing I thought of, but seems like I can't change Tabindex, they are all set on the same number 2147483647. I guess I don't know how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what Watermark is, but usually this would be caused by you intercepting the Tab and doing something, then the event bubbling up and being handled again by the default handler.

Try consuming the event, so that this does not happen. Might be something like e.preventDefault(), or e.stopPropagation()

Comment: this gave me an idea. I added e.Handled = true on the tabbing, and it ran almost as if any other site. Thanks.